# How to get the key, value and index in a Dictionary loop?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to loop it and get the key, value and it's index as `Int`, but with my loop, I'm just only getting the key and value, how can I get the index?

This is my code for getting its key and value:

```swift
var myDict:[String: String]?

func getKeyValueIndex() {
    if let myDict = myDict {
        for (key, value) in myDict { print(key, value) }
    }
}
```

My expected result was to print the index too `print(key, value, index)`

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered so there is not much point in getting the index so using key, value to iterate is all you need

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm thinking to use the index for counting the dictionary content down with a unique int value

Comment: So all you want to do is to count down you can use `myDict.keys.count` and do it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered, so all you can do is  to enumerate through the dictionary, like this:

```
func getKeyValueIndex() {
    if let myDict = myDict {
        for (index, dict) in myDict.enumerated() { print(index, dict.key, dict.value) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dict are unordered so this code doesnt get the same id what we want

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik How do you know what "we want"? The answer is correct based on the info the OP gave.

Comment: Key and value not ordered but index is. So indexes and key, value doesnt match. That I want to say @matt

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik But a dictionary's index is not "ordered" either. You could index your way through the very same dictionary on different occasions and find a different index corresponding to the same key-value pair.